# Prepared statement not returning results for string numbers

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to retrieve records from oracle database for the SQL query - `SELECT data FROM test where id = ?;`

Here is my code to retrieve the data -

```
public static String retrieveData(String id) throws IOException {
    String result = "";
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT data FROM test where id = ?";
            connection = getDBConnection(); //this method gets the db connection
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, id);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                result = result + rs.getString("data");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeDBConnection(); //closes db connection
        }
        return result;
    }
```

When I invoke the retrieveData in the main method, it returns null. When I debug, the resultSet is empty. I am guessing the reason is I am passing my id as String, but perhaps Oracle doesn't understand something like - `SELECT data FROM test where id = "1234567890";`

Can someone please guide me how do I fix this? I have tried way too many things, but I can't seem to fetch the data from the db for this id. I also tried converting the id to long using `Long.valueOf(String s).longValue();` and setting this as the placeholder in ps.setLong, but it didn't help. Please advise.

Comment: What type is the `id` column in the database?

Comment: It is VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)

Comment: Have you tried executing the same query against your Oracle database in another tool like Toad?

Comment: Do you have data related to that `id` in DB ?

Comment: I don't believe it's going to return `null` - but it might be returning an empty string. It doesn't help that if anything goes wrong, you're just printing the stack trace but continuing... have you checked whether or not that *is* what's happening? Have you debugged through the code to see what happens?

Comment: @Jon - Yes, it is returning an empty string.

Comment: Okay, it may be worth updating your question to indicate that then. And again, have you debugged through the code? Does it get as far as the `while` loop?

Comment: Please run the query that is being generated here in your oracle sql directly and see if it is still returning empty or a value. If former is true, then you are putting wrong id values and if latter is true, well, I am not sure I will be able to help.

Comment: I have tried for the same id, and there are records. I have infact tried for every single id in the db, and my code, and my code returns an empty string for every id that works fine when executed in the DB.

Comment: PLease check the following
1. DB is correct
2. Check wothout setting id and see if results come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Type issue of `id` column

This is probably due to spacing difference or another subtle difference that gives the impression that they are the same.

The strings `' 123  '` or `'00123'` (for example) are **not** equivalent to `'123'` in `VARCHAR2` type, while they **are** equivalent in `NUMERIC` type, as *Oracle* converts all those strings to the numeral `123`.

You are better off using a `NUMERIC` column as your `id` to avoid such problems. It also makes sense to limit your valid `id` values to whole numbers, rather than any arbitrary string.

With *Oracle* you can continue to use `setString` as it will automatically cast the string to an integer. But I recommend you to use `setInt` or `setLong` instead (after the conversion of the `id` column), as other database solutions like *Postgres* will not accept a string to match a `NUMERIC` column.

---

### Exception handling issue

When you catch a `Throwable` or an `Exception` (or their subtypes), be sure to think about whether it can be ignored, or it must be thrown for further handling (for example, to stop the program, alert the user or correct the problem).

In your code, the catch block catches the `SQLException` and prints the stack trace. But it doesn't do anything else.

```
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } ...
```

This means that you are ignoring the exception and continuing the program as though *nothing happened*. The execution will continue on to `return result;` after completing the `finally` block.

The caller of your method will never know that an `SQLException` occurred, and it will **wrongly assume that there were no errors** and the returned data is correct.

Unless that is what you really want, what you ought to do is as follows:

```
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); //it doesn't matter what you do here. the next line is what's important.
            throw e; //throw the exception after printing stack trace, logging, etc.
        } ...
```

In this case your method will throw the `SQLException` to the caller after completing the `finally` block. The execution will **not** continue to `return result;`.

This way the caller of your method will receive the exception and **know that an error has occurred**. The caller can then act accordingly; for example, by stopping the program, alerting the user or retrying the method with a different input.

Comment: I used the setLong too. Like I mentioned in my post.

Comment: setLong is only going to work properly if your id column is numeric type. Also please throw the exception after catching it. Right now you're just printing the stact trace but continuing as though nothing happened.

Comment: What do you mean by throwing the exception after catching it? Jon mentioned it too. Can you please edit your post, and explain that?

Comment: I've edited as requested. Please see the explanation.

Comment: Thanks so much. Can I do a System.out.println? Something like this? System.out.println("Error occured while retrieving records from the database :" + e.getMessage());

Comment: You can do anything you want, but as long as you are not throwing the exception (`throw e;`) after that, you are basically ignoring the exception and continuing as though **nothing happened**. Try to understand the difference in flow with and without the `throw` statement.

Answer (score 0):

may be the reason is DEBUG. if you have a breakpoint on the line "while(rs.next())" and you watch/inspect it then then rs increments one. Then the code executes rs.next for the second time where there is no record.
maybe...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use datatype 'String' for id field, it can cause serious trouble. Try to covert it to numeric datatype is possible but why don't you use numeric at first. You should change to int or bigint. In additional try to catch exception like this:

```
try{

}catch(SQLException ex){
    System.out.println("Error at:" +ex.getClass().getName() + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Try it again, if you can't debug it and find out why! Good luck!

Comment: Err, you rehashed my answer. And you didn't even use `throw` in the `catch` block.

Comment: I think this ways is more convenient. It shows where's error and class causes exception!

Comment: Yeah, but you're also missing the point. Your program will continue on like *nothing happened* even if there is an error and it should stop.

Comment: ya! you're right, I just use this way when face to serious error which terminate program. So the best way is yours! just use my way when error cause termination!

Comment: If a program doesn't terminate when there is a serious error, it's a terrible program. It pretends to work fine when it doesn't work. Unless that is what you really want, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I don't think so! With minor error program still run properly! I agree that, when something wrong occur we need to fix it! But to minor error is different. Program still run its progress, data is not wrong, that's call Transparency!

Comment: *"But to minor error is different."* You said *serious error* in your previous comment. And the term *minor* is also too vague. You should say "an error that is expected and can be ignored" as opposed to "an error that is unexpected and should be handled".

Comment: I think you missunderstood! Serious error must be fixed immediately! but sometime, with minor error is difference one! Let suppose that, you fix all bug in a program and release it. It cause some minor error but everything still fine! That's what I mean

Answer (score -1):

Please try this. Remove all the spaces when defining field name with a ? and check

```
 SELECT data FROM test where id=?
```

Comment: This wouldn't make any difference. You can put as many spaces as you want before and after the `?`. The parametrized type will not see them.